# IIS worker process taking high CPU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, iis7

I have a 3 server farm (APP, WFE, DB)

On my WFE I am running a publishing site. Problem is on this server when you open the site, the IIS Worker Process takes a lot of CPU time. The same site on another farm works fine. Upon investigation it turns out that the w3wp.exe process running under user "sp_services" is taking high CPU.

I have used this "sp_services" user to configure all application pools.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your code, are objects disposed properly?
2. If you have too many visits at the same time I would say CPU high would be normal.
3. Check that you are using page cache, output cache, object cache and blob cache, that will reduce roundtrips to db server and should lower cpu usage.

and last, but  not least you have to identify somehow which pages are the ones that are giving headaches, sometimes bad developed web parts can cause this.

Answer (score 1):

What the performance Impact on the SharePoint Sites, loading slowly or normal?

I would check the ULS logs as well as enable the Developer Dashboard, then check which item causing this issue.

Did you try to recycle the App Pool?

also make sure, if you have custom webpart or other customization, no memory leak from them.

You can also try to close the web part on the home page and try to add one by one then check the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible given you environment, you should enable the [Developer Dashboard](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html).  It could help identify if particular components of the page are causing resource issues.